# Is it possible to programmatically generate Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse, ant

Greetings

I'm working on a product that is composed of loooots of small eclipse projects. We maintain .project files, and generate .classpath files using ivy, so the handling of each individual project is easy.

However, what is more painfull is to create a workspace containing all the projects. It happens infrequently enough (basically every time we branch all the code for realease and stuff).

Does anyone know of a way to create Eclipse *workspaces* programatically ? Something that would make it possible to write an ant task to :

- create a workspace in a new folder
- automatically 'import' existing projects (from an existing svn checkout)
- create Linked Resource / workspace variable
- (optionnaly, create a team sharing location and connect projects to SVN ...)

Comment: Open an eclipse project file, read it, create something that looks the same.

Comment: As I wrote, I already have .project files, what I'm interested is workspace - from what I understand it corresponds to the content of the .metadata folder, which is not something I want to generate entirely by hand

Comment: @Yochai: it is about making a workspace, not a project. A workspace is more complex and relevant information (formatting, launch configs, etc.) is spread on several files (some are binary...) in several folders...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automatically import a predefined set of projects via *File>Import*, then *Team>Team Project Set*. (You can define the set via a prior use of the sibling *File>Export* menu item.)